# Error when attempting to set pie chart title using C# Excel Interop

Tags: c#, excel, charts, interop

I am creating an Excel pie chart using Excel Interop. The chart is being created correctly, however when I go to set the title, I get a runtime exception that states: "This object has no title.".

Here is the code I am using:

```
 Excel.ChartObjects dayTypeWorksheetCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)dayTypeWorksheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);

     int dayTypeDistributionChartLeft = 10;
     int dayTypeDistributionChartTop = 10;
     int dayTypeDistributionChartWidth = 700;
     int dayTypeDistributionChartHeight = 500;

     Excel.ChartObject dayTypeDistributionChart = (Excel.ChartObject)dayTypeWorksheetCharts.Add(
        dayTypeDistributionChartLeft,
        dayTypeDistributionChartTop,
        dayTypeDistributionChartWidth,
        dayTypeDistributionChartHeight);

     Excel.Chart dayTypeDistributionChartPage = dayTypeDistributionChart.Chart;
     dayTypeDistributionChartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlPie;

     Excel.SeriesCollection seriesCollection = (Excel.SeriesCollection) dayTypeDistributionChartPage.SeriesCollection(Type.Missing);
     Excel.Series series1 = seriesCollection.NewSeries();

     Excel.Range startingLabelCell = (Excel.Range)dayTypeWorksheet.Cells[2, DayTypeWorksheetColumnIndices.title];
     Excel.Range endingLabelCell = (Excel.Range)dayTypeWorksheet.Cells[10, DayTypeWorksheetColumnIndices.title];
     Excel.Range labelRange = (Excel.Range)dayTypeWorksheet.get_Range(startingLabelCell, endingLabelCell);

     Excel.Range startingDataCell = (Excel.Range)dayTypeWorksheet.Cells[2, DayTypeWorksheetColumnIndices.frequencyPercentage];
     Excel.Range endingDataCell = (Excel.Range)dayTypeWorksheet.Cells[10, DayTypeWorksheetColumnIndices.frequencyPercentage];
     Excel.Range dataRange = (Excel.Range)dayTypeWorksheet.get_Range(startingDataCell, endingDataCell);

     series1.XValues = labelRange;
     series1.Values = dataRange;
        dayTypeDistributionChartPage.ChartTitle.Text = "Day Type Distribution";
     series1.ApplyDataLabels(Excel.XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowPercent, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, Type.Missing);
```

When I comment out the line that sets the chart title, the error goes away and "Chart Title" is the title of the chart.

Googling took me to this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/baf3e9cc-4330-4ae9-9a34-32e4865b35f7) but the answer gave me a different error and did not fix my issue.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: i think you must set `HasTitle` property to true first

Comment: Didn't help. Tried adding the command `         dayTypeDistributionChartPage.HasTitle = true;` and while that command alone doesn't cause an exception, uncommenting out the command that sets the Chart title text still results in an exception.